# Table not found when seeding

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-migrations, laravel-seeding

Below are my migrations

[image: Migrations]

The users table have a relation with the customer table

In user:

```
$table->integer('customer_id')->unsigned();
$table->foreign('customer_id')->references('id')->on('customers');
```

When i call `php artisan migrate:refresh --seed`, artisan given me the following error:

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]                                         
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL  
  : alter table `users` add constraint `users_customer_id_foreign` foreign ke  
  y (`customer_id`) references `customers` (`id`))                             



  [PDOException]                                                          
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint
```

Because the customers table does not exists... (obvious)

Is there a way to solve this problem? I know changing the date of the files will fix this but there should be a beter approach

Comment: Rename the `customers`  table migration file so that it appears before `users` table migration file. Now drop database and run your command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create the table you're referencing to before adding the foreign key. A solution would be to remove the foreign key constraint from your user table migration and create a new migration which adds the foreign key constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make it separately.

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('costumer_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });

   Schema::table('users', function($table) {
       $table->foreign('costumer_id')->references('id')->on('costumers');
   });
}
```

Another thing you can try(since laravel 5.3):

```
unsignedInteger('column_name') instead of ('column_name')-unsigned()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you had set one field as "Unsigned" and other one not. Once you should set both columns to Unsigned it works.